# Чем на уровне реализации gui являются вкладки?

Tags: linux, c, gui, opengl, x11

Чем на уровне реализации  gui  являются вкладки ? Под вкладками я имею ввиду вкладки браузер, вкладки с файлами кода в idea, которые при желании можно вынести в отдельные окна. Это окна на уровне условного x11(если говорить про линукс)? Или это просто поверхности созданные в графическом api(opengl, directx)?

Comment: Ни тем, ни другим. Приложение как-то само (как именно — зависит от конкретного приложения) рисует желаемую картинку отдаёт на отрисовку готовую картинку (в X11/Wayland сервер если говорить про линукс)

Comment: @andreymal вопрос состоит в том, какой дефолтный метод для реализации подобного виджета

Comment: Дефолтного не существует, каждый делает как хочет

Comment: Абстракцией, ничего более